# tcpdump not capturing packets but Apache log shows the request

Tags: tcpdump

I'm trying to debug a client side javascript application that sends a XMLHttpRequest to a php script but I don't get any output from tcpdump when this happens. Apache logs the request, the script itself throws an error because there were no POST or GET variables and the web console shows a 200 response code - but no output from tcpdump. I do get tcpdump output loading the webpage that contains the javascript, but once javascript sends its request there's nothing...  I'm stumped...

tcpdump version 4.9.2
libpcap version 1.5.3

My tcpdump command

```
tcpdump -p -vvv -i enp4s0 'src myclientip and not port 22'
```

Apache log of the XMLHttpRequest

```
myclientip - - [23/Apr/2020:11:41:42 -0700] "GET /newSite/addressHints.php?query=999 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://mywebsite/newSite/typeaheadTest.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT  10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
```

Comment: What if you try without -p ?

Comment: Can that be a buffering problem? If you reload the page, does `tcpdump` show the missing packets?

Comment: Promiscuous mode made no difference. If I reload the page, I get output for the page load but nothing when the script sends it's request,  But I do get a record of it in the Apache log and in the web console.

Comment: Changing -i enp4s0 to -i any so tecpump listens on all interfaces will help if traffic is not going through that specific interface. (also I'm not sure the single quotes are desirable - they aren't needed there, try removing them)

Comment: Removed the quotes, same results. This is a production server, only one interface for traffic to go through...

Comment: Perhaps the xhr goes via a proxy, apache registers the x-forwarded for. Try without src ip.

Comment: Can you run `tcpdump` (or the like) on the client?